# How to display a clickable list of things to datagrid cell?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid, in one of the columns I want to display a string - in each cell in the column a different string(that I get from the user) that looks like this: "data1, data2, data3, ..." and make each datai(data1,data2,...) clickable.
how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is edited version:

1. Xaml (put it inside the `<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate`):

   ```
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type soDataGridHeplAttempt:ClicableItemsModel}">
                       <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding ClickableItems}">
                           <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                               <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                               </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                           </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                           <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                               <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                   <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                       <Setter.Value>
                                           <DataTemplate>
                                               <Button  Width="70" Content="{Binding }" Style="{StaticResource ButtonInCellStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                                        Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.Command}" 
                                                        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}"/>
                                           </DataTemplate>
                                       </Setter.Value>
                                   </Setter>
                               </Style>
                           </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                       </ListBox>
                   </DataTemplate>
   ```
2. Xaml resources use this if you want to edit the button content:

   ```
      <Style x:Key="ButtonInCellStyle" TargetType="Button">
      <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
          <Setter.Value>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBox Background="{x:Null}" MaxWidth="40" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=Content,  Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ToolTip="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}">
                   </TextBox>
               </DataTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
   ```
3. Viewmodel:

   ```
   private ICommand _command;
   public ObservableCollection<ClicableItemsModel> Strings { get; set; }

   public ICommand Command
   {
       get { return _command ?? (_command = new RelayCommand<object>(MethodOnCommmand)); }
   }

   private void MethodOnCommmand(object obj)
   {

   }
   ```
4. Clickable Items model code (create the ClicableItemsModel class an put it there):

   ```
   public ObservableCollection<String> ClickableItems { get; set; }
   ```
5. when running:
   [image]

regards,